# R package development: how to check whether the type of SEXP is "big.matrix"?

Tags: c, r, r-bigmemory

I am developing an R package with low-level C code. Suppose I have following function in my `C` code.

```
SEXP myFun(SEXP obj)
```

I need to know whether the R object `obj` is a regular `matrix` or `big.matrix` (use R package `bigmemory`) so that I can call different functions for computation.

Is this possible? How could I know the class type of `obj`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [inherits](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/ef64d69d5c480d9f63485c6165eedb66c5ba513c/src/include/Rinternals.h#L1287) function:

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>

SEXP myFun(SEXP obj) {
    if (inherits(obj, "big.memory")) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin. That's exactly what I ended up with.

Comment: Nice, and if you end up with Rcpp headers this becomes `Rf_inherits()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're open to C++ (rather than C) then we have two [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org) posts for you:

- [BigMemory with Rcpp](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-bigmemory-with-rcpp/)
- [BigMemory with RcppArmadillo](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-bigmemory-with-rcpparmadillo/)

The narrow answer is probably testing for external pointer `SEXP` in an S4 class... but then I don't really do plain C anymore as Rcpp makes things so much easier.

Comment: Thank you very much for developing ``Rcpp``, Dirk. I am exactly learning ``Rcpp``, and using it to handle computation for ``big.matrix``. My problem is that I am extending an existing R package where the algorithm is already implemented in C. I only need to write code to deal with ``big.matrix`` part.

Comment: That is *not* a constraint.  You can write as much (or little) C++ around an inner C core.  Remember that R itself is a C (and some Fortran) program too.  So in short use Rcpp here too.  It should make your task easier.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, Dirk. If I can check the class type of ``SEXP`` at C/C++ level, then I can use ``Rcpp`` to handle ``big.matrix``, and use existing ``C`` code for the rest. But I am still not clear how your suggestion could solve this. If possible, could you revise your answer with more details so that I can accept your answer?

Comment: It's all in the gallery post(s) and has been done before.  Yes, you can check SEXP type. Yes, you can check `attr()`.  And for starters you would NOT use `SEXP foo(SEXP x)` but rather use types -- eg `Rcpp::XPtr`.

Comment: Thanks. That's really helpful!!